# Combinations to crack code

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of numbers from 0 to 9

```
numbers=Range[0,9,1]
```

I want to determine the combination of three numbers between 0 and 9. There is a correct combination through the conditions below:

**1 - There is a true number in the correct position**

[image]

```
condition1={6,8,2};
Permutations[condition1]
```

> {{6,8,2},{6,2,8},{8,6,2},{8,2,6},{2,6,8},{2,8,6}}

**2 - There is a true number, however, in the wrong position**

[image]

```
condition2={6,1,4};
Permutations[condition2]
```

> {{6, 1, 4}, {6, 4, 1}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 1}, {4, 1, 6}}

**3 - There are two true numbers, however, in incorrect positions**

[image]

```
condition3 = {2, 0, 6};
Permutations[condition3]
```

> {{2, 0, 6}, {2, 6, 0}, {0, 2, 6}, {0, 6, 2}, {6, 2, 0}, {6, 0, 2}}

**4 - All Fake Numbers**

[image]

```
condition4 = {7, 3, 8};
Complement[numbers, condition4]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9}

**5 - There is a true number, however, in the wrong position**

[image]

```
condition5 = {7, 8, 0};
Permutations[condition5]
```

> {{7, 8, 0}, {7, 0, 8}, {8, 7, 0}, {8, 0, 7}, {0, 7, 8}, {0, 8, 7}}

I tried combining these solutions, but I did not get a answer through a code. I only have the result using my logic ...

[image]

Comment: does "a true number, however, in the wrong position" mean "a true number, however,_not necessarily_  in the correct position" or "a _single_ true number, _AND_ it is in the wrong position"? Similarly for "two true numbers, however, in incorrect positions"?

Comment: .. are the three numbers distinct?

Comment: Can you please edit and streamline your question?  Trivial example:  `Range[0,9]` (not `Range[0,9,1]`).  But those unnecessary graphics require us to scroll needlessly.  The whole thing can be sharpened up; it will attract more helpers.  Also you can be clearer if you distinguish between *digit* and *number*.  After all, $423$ is a number, but you don't want it to be considered as such.  Needlessly confusing!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming (1)  possible codes are triples with distinct elements and (2) "in the wrong position"  means *not necessarily in the correct position*:

```
ClearAll[containsOneCP, containsOne, containsTwo, containsNone]

containsOneCP[lst_] :=  Module[{abc = MapThread[Equal, {#, lst}]}, 
    BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, 3][## & @@ abc]] &;

containsOne[lst_] := Length[Intersection[#, lst]] == 1 &;

containsTwo[lst_] := Length[Intersection[#, lst]] == 2 &;

containsNone[lst_] := ContainsNone[lst];

conditions = {condition1, condition2, condition3, condition4, condition5};

funcs = {containsOneCP, containsOne, containsTwo, containsNone, containsOne};

flist = MapThread[# @ #2 &, {funcs, conditions}];

Select[And @@ Through[flist @ #] &] @ Permutations[Range[0, 9], {3}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 2},{0, 4, 2},{1, 0, 2},{4, 0, 2},{6, 0, 5},{6, 0, 9},{6, 5, 0},{6, 9, 0}}
> ```

**Update:** If "a true number / two true numbers, however, in the wrong position"  means the one digit is (the two digits are) **not** in their correct positions, we need to add the condition `(And @@ MapThread[Unequal, {#, lst}])` to `containsOne` and `containsTwo`:

```
containsOneWP[lst_] := (And @@ MapThread[Unequal, {#, lst}]) && 
    Length[Intersection[#, lst]] == 1 &;

containsTwoWP[lst_] := (And @@ MapThread[Unequal, {#, lst}]) && 
    Length[Intersection[#, lst]] == 2 &;
```

With this modification we get a unique result that matches OP's manually obtained result:

```
funcs2 = {containsOneCP, containsOneWP, containsTwoWP, containsNone, containsOneWP};

flist2 = MapThread[#@#2 &, {funcs2, conditions}];

Select[And @@ Through[flist2@#] &]@Permutations[Range[0, 9], {3}]
```

> ```
>  {{0, 4, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Cases[Permutations[Range[0,9],{3}],
  v:{a_,b_,c_}/;
  And[
    (a==6||b==8||c==2)&&Length[v⋂{6,8,2}]==1,
    (a!=6&&b!=1&&c!=4)&&Length[v⋂{6,1,4}]==1,
    (a!=2&&b!=0&&c!=6)&&Length[v⋂{2,0,6}]==2,
    (a!=7&&b!=3&&c!=8),
    (a!=7&&b!=8&&c!=0)&&Length[v⋂{7,8,0}]==1
  ]
]
```

> {{0, 4, 2}}

Answer (score 1):

One possible interpretation?

```
Permutations[Range[0,9,1],{3}]//condition1//condition2//condition3
```

> {{0, 4, 2}}

```
 condition1:=Cases[#, {6, Except[8|2], Except[2|8]}|
      {Except[6|2], 8, Except[2|6]} |
      {Except[6|8], Except[8|6], 2}]&

  condition2:=Cases[#, {Except[6], 6|4, Except[4]} |
      {Except[6], Except[1], 1|6}|
      {1|4, Except[1], Except[4]}]&

  condition3:=Cases[#, {Except[2], 2|6, 2|0} | 
        {0|6, Except[0], 2|0}|
        {6|0,6|2,Except[6]}]&
```